# Dynamic Linq Datetime where

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

im using dynamic linq in order to build a query  and im having an issue with **DateTime**

- queryResults- contain a list of result from a previous  query .
- sr.FromDate- a DateTime parameter

what im trying to do is to get the all the result that greater and equal to the sr.FromDate parameter

```
var z = queryResults
            .Where("Min(Datetime) >= @0", sr.FromDate)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.FirstOrDefault().ServiceInstanceId, g => g.ToList());
```

exeption:

```
ParseError  ,    '.' or '(' expected
```

**EDIT:**

just to Clarify we im using dynamic linq   **SR** object contains string int and date parameters 
if the values of the parameters isnt null im building a query

**EDIT 2**

i figure out my privus problem  but now i have another problem , im using this in order to build the query

```
  private static string GetQueryTemplet(string criteria)
    {

        switch (criteria)
        {

            case "FromDate":
                return " Min(Track.Datetime) >= {0} ";
            case "ToDate":
                return " Max(Track.Datetime) <=  {0} ";

             default:
                return "";
        }
```

than im passing the data to

```
 var z = queryResolts
             .Where(query)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(h => h.Track));
```

for some reason im getting this exception

```
Operator '>=' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime' and 'Int32'
```

i tried to parse it in many ways but nothing work ...

thanks 
miki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your results have a DateTime Column

```
var z = queryResults
            .Where(result => result.DateTime >= sr.FromDate)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.FirstOrDefault().ServiceInstanceId, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: i have to use dynamic linq http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: @MIkCode why? You're not gaining any benefit from it in this exact scenario. Do you need to dynamically change the column name or something?  If not; don't use it because you don't need it.